# Mocking frameworks for WinRT?

Tags: mocking, windows-runtime

It feels like I've got to be missing something, but I haven't been able to find any mock-object frameworks I can use when I'm writing unit tests for my WinRT code. Are there any WinRT-capable mocking frameworks out there?

I'm aware of [MoqRT](https://github.com/mbrit/moqrt), but as far as I can tell, it does codegen at build time (though via a fragile-sounding integration that's not quite part of the actual build process), but it feels more like a hack than an implementation.

DynamicMethod (the class behind Lightweight Code Generation) apparently isn't available in WinRT. But expression trees do seem to be supported, including their Compile method; so it seems like a mock-object framework should be doable, probably.

Are there any WinRT mocking frameworks out there?

Answer (score 5):

I've been using Telerik JustMock in WinRT. You don't get a useful error message when the test fails, but apart from that, you're away. It's the full paid version I've got, not the free one, I don't know if that works.

Also, you might want to consider if you really need to have your code in WinRT assemblies - check out Portable Class Libraries, and call them from your WinRT app. I might be proved wrong by reality, but I would think you would be able to use mocking frameworks on code in a PCL

Comment: Moving your code to a PCL won't solve the problem. If the PCL targets WinRT (which is required if you want to reference your code from your WinRT project), the relevant namespaces that are required for most mocking frameworks (System.Reflection.Emit) are still gone.

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently stuck with the same problem. I'm sad that Rhino Mocks is not working on WinRT. But apparetnly there is a port of Moq => [MoqRT](https://github.com/mbrit/MoqRT)

I haven't used it, I'll probably investigate in fakes, stubs and shims from Microsoft; Since MoqRT is still alpha and I don't want to test my code with an alpha framework.

But just pointing out another possibility.

**UPDATE**

I just found out about this: [Fake It Easy](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2013/02/01/fakeiteasy-and-windows-store-apps-are-becoming-friends/)

Haven't tried it but it looks promising.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned MoqRT in my question, along with some of its downsides.

Answer (score 0):

Mocking isn't possible in WinRT:

- http://geekswithblogs.net/mbrit/archive/2012/06/05/say-goodbye-to-system.reflection.emit-any-dynamic-proxy-generation-in-winrt.aspx

However, it does look like Microsoft will be supporting their auto-generated "Fake Assemblies" in the near future though:

- http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=790
- http://www.richonsoftware.com/post/2012/04/05/Using-Stubs-and-Shim-to-Test-with-Microsoft-Fakes-in-Visual-Studio-11.aspx

Comment: Your first link says that System.Reflection.Emit is missing in WinRT (which appears to be true), but it completely ignores expression trees -- which, as I said in my question, are apparently supported in WinRT. So I'm not convinced by that post; it looks like he was just looking for the API he was used to, but missed out on another API that can accomplish the same thing.

Comment: The problem with Microsoft's Fake Assemblies is that you need VS Ultimate to get them.